# What is going on with my hard drives?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, filevault

I bought a fairly cheap old MacBook Pro (Mid 2014) from Facebook Marketplace a couple days ago because I wanted to try out using a Mac, but what is confusing me is my hard disks. I assumed there was only one 256 gb hard drive, but there seem to be two at least?
[image: screenshot of my Disk Utility app showing several HDs]

There's the regular Macintosh HD, which for some reason contains another one called "com.apple.os.update-*string-of-numbers*" (created after I reset the computer to factory settings and re-installed the OS there), mounted at /, then there's a "Macintosh HD - Data" with an uppercase D (seen in the screenshot), mounted at /System/Volumes/Data, one that has a lowercase D and is "not mounted", and one that also has a lowercase D, mounted at /Volumes/Macintosh HD – data.

The weirdest part is every time I start up the computer it asks for a password that I don't know to unlock the files on one of the "HD - data" disks. I don't care to know what's in there, this was just what made me realize there was something unusual going on.
[image: screenshot of the request to unlock disk "Macintosh HD - data"]

Even though it says it's locked, it still seems like I can access some of it through the Finder, like launch apps that don't seem to be installed on the computer from the Applications folder, but I can't see anything relating to the "HD - Data" with the uppercase D.
[image]

I'm sure there's a lot of confusing information here, I'm sorry, I would just like to know what's going on and what I can do to get rid of this request for a password - format the disks maybe? And how can I figure out what physical hard drives are actually on my computer?

EDIT: results of `diskutil list`:

```
0: GUID_partition_scheme  *251.0 GB  disk0
1:  EFI ⁨EFI⁩  209.7 MB  disk0s1
2:  Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩  250.8 GB  disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
0:  APFS Container Scheme - Physical Store disk0s2  +250.8 GB  disk1
1:  APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD – data⁩  13.7 GB  disk1s1
2:  APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩  902.3 MB  disk1s2
3:  APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩  1.9 GB  disk1s3
4:  APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩   1.1 GB  disk1s4
5:  APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD – data⁩  14.6 GB  disk1s5
6:  APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD - Data⁩  22.0 GB  disk1s7
7:  APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD⁩  15.3 GB  disk1s8
8:  APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩  15.3 GB  disk1s8s1
```

Comment: In the top left menus of Disk Utility > View > tick Show all Devices. That shows the single physical disk more clearly.

Comment: Alright, thanks for that, makes it more clear. So what do I do with all of these I'm guessing partitions? Should I somehow unify all of them? And how do I get rid of the lock that was put on it?

Comment: Can you give us the results of `diskutil list`   ???

Answer (score 2):

Normally, a Mac drive has two volumes: "Macintosh HD" (which actually just contains the OS, and is read-only); and "Macintosh HD - Data", which contains everything else.

The Finder then presents this pair to you as one seamless volume.

The request for a password means that the volume is encrypted, but that the authentication keys are not setup correctly to be automatically used at boot.

Normally, "reset to factory" means only deleting the Data volume. The OS is 'secure-sealed', so is guaranteed to be untouched.

It's possible that by reinstalling the OS, you've actually installed it on the Data volume, which has thus created its own Data pair.

Wiping the whole disk and reinstalling is largely unnecessary on MacOS; but in your case, you may have to start again.

Comment: Well I followed a tutorial on reinstalling the OS and remember choosing Macintosh HD, and you can also see that the "com.apple.os.update..." is under Macintosh HD, so that should be correct, no? If I can just wipe the volume that's asking to be unlocked and keep the 3 data volumes I think that would be fine. Could and should I do that?

Comment: Also sorry to sound stupid but how should I share what I got from diskutil list? Because it's too long for a comment.

Comment: @who.is.artis Edit your question, and paste the text in there.